# A man is shrunk in a submarine and goes inside another man's body

Tags: story-identification, movie

A movie about a man that is driving a capsule inside another man's blood stream. He controls his face by changing it to another man.

Comment: it could also be "Fantastic Voyage" (1966) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060397/

Comment: @Rocket yeah that was my original answer, but Fantasic Voyage, which is the inspiration for Innerspace, doesn't include face morphing.

Comment: @TrishLing yes i know... there is this aspect of Innerspace i did not like

Answer (score 23):

[Innerspace (1987)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innerspace):

> Down-on-his-luck naval aviator Lt. Tuck Pendleton (Quaid) resigns his
> commission and volunteers for a secret miniaturization experiment. He
> is placed in a submersible pod, and both are shrunk to microscopic
> size. They are transferred into a syringe to be injected into a
> rabbit, but the lab is attacked by a rival organization led by
> scientist Dr. Margaret Canker (Fiona Lewis) planning to seize the
> experiment and steal their technology.
>
> Experiment supervisor Ozzie Wexler (John Hora), knowing their
> intentions, escapes with the syringe. A chase ensues with one of
> Canker's henchman and leads to a nearby shopping mall. After being
> fatally shot and knowing he is about to die, he injects Tuck and the
> pod into an unsuspecting Jack Putter (Martin Short), a hypochondriac
> grocery store clerk who happens to be the first person he comes into
> contact with.

Face control:

> By contacting Tuck's estranged girlfriend Lydia Maxwell (Meg Ryan),
> who has had dealings with the Cowboy, they learn that the Cowboy plans
> to buy the computer chip from Scrimshaw. After knocking the Cowboy
> unconscious using the pod's equipment, Tuck controls the muscles of
> Jack's face to make it look like the Cowboy's, and with him posing as
> the Cowboy, they meet with Scrimshaw and steal the chip from him.
> However, as they're about to take possession of the chip, Jack's
> nervousness overrides the transformation of his face, exposing the
> scam.

Fantastic Voyage, which I answered with originally, is the inspiration for Innerspace (but doesn't include the face morphing).

Face Morph clip (low-qual):

Answer (score 15):

This movie is called [Innerspace (1987).](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093260/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_54)

> A hapless store clerk must foil criminals to save the life of the man who, miniaturized in a secret experiment, was accidentally injected into him.

At one point he changes the appearance of Martin Short to look like 'The Cowboy.'

[image]

Comment: Yes this the one thank you very much

Comment: @user38821 you should click on a check-mark to show that answer is accepted. Check out [this article in help center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)